# Remember me cookie forgery

Tags: php, cookies, remember-me

When a user log in and check the "remember me" box, I generate a key (very random numbers on a md5) for it and save on it's cookies. If the user is not logged, my code check for a "remember me key" cookie, if it matches with a user, then he's logged in.

My question is, how do I stop users from coping their remember me key cookie and pass it to their friends? Because if they do that, the person who copied the cookie will be logged in without even knowing the password of the account, then they would access a premium account without buying it.

I can't bind the key to the ip, or else the remember me wouldn't work well, since lots of computers change ips very often. I though about saving the user agent and others browser infos, what do you think?

Comment: In the same vein:  What would stop a user from giving a friend their username and password?  You're assuming your users are working together, and sharing a UN/PW seems a lot easier than copying a cookie that's going to expire anyway...

Comment: yeah but giving this cookie and not the password, he could send the cookie to a lot of people, and nobody would be able to change the password and get the account for it's own, only the main owner

Comment: Then limit the number of concurrent sessions per paid user to 1.

Comment: I already logout a user if the same account is logged elsewhere, but then with the "remember me key" the user would only login again, the solution is to generate a new key every time the remember key is used

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can detect the sharing of cookies by regenerating the key for the cookie each time it's used. If someone gives a remember-me cookie to someone else (or it's stolen) and they both use it, then they will both end up with different keys after they use their cookie.

Only allow the most recently generated key for each account. If someone uses a key that doesn't match the database value, then invalidate all sessions associated with the user.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, how do I stop users from coping their remember me key
>   cookie and pass it to their friends?

Best solution is not to use remember me:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Guide_to_Authentication#Remember_Me

If you still want to then you could check the requesters browser and ip but then maybe your have useability issues. Limiting the number of concurrent sessions to 1 per paid user may deter the exploit you are concerned about.

Comment: yeah, like when the user updates their browser (with chrome is almost every week), but i don't want to remove the remember me function, it's very important for my website